# Rails: Iterating with Uneven Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, `Friends`, that I want to iterate in a view, but I'm having trouble with because I'm having to use uneven column widths.

Normally, if the column widths were constant, I would do some thing like this:

```
<% @user.friends.each do |friend|%>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= friend.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, because of the layout I'm working with, I need to put an offset in the first column:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
```

and I don't want the offset in the second column:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

How can I iterate through `@user.friends` with alternating column widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through the list using `each_with_index` and add conditional css class based on odd/even value of the index

```
<% @user.friends.each_with_index do |friend, index| %>
  <div class="<%= (index).even? ? 'col-md-5 col-md-offset-1' : 'col-md-6' %>">
    <%= friend.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<% @user.friends.each_with_index do |friend, index|%>
<% if index == 0 %>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= friend.name %>
  </div>
<% else %> 
  <div class="col-md-6"> #whatever offset u need 
    <%= friend.name %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc.. `friend` the offset.

```
<% odd = true %>
<% @user.friends.each do |friend|%>
  <%= raw(odd ? '<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">' : '<div class="col-md-6">') %>
    <%= friend.name %>
  </div>
  <% odd = !odd %>
<% end %>
```